# IntelliJ: debugging Web App which is using embedded server

Tags: java, scala, debugging, intellij-idea, web-applications

It is very easy to debug Web applications using common application servers ([Tomcat](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html), Jetty, GlassFish, Google App Engine ...) in IntelliJ Ultimate as [Run/Debug configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configurations.html) are provided for them.

What I find difficult and inconvenient is debugging an application which is using embedded server. I can found a configuration for debugging either the server (it is debugged as an ordinary JVM [application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-application.html)) or the client (as [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html)), but I did not find anything which would both run the application and open a debuggable browser.

An example of the project I would like to debug is [Akka HTTP with Scala.js](https://github.com/vmunier/akka-http-with-scalajs-example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question to the support and their answer was this is currently not possible. I have created a feature request at [the IDEA issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166538).